# Регулярное выражение неправильно делит на группы, как исправить?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Есть [регулярное выражение](http://regexr.com/3b9pc), которое находит правильные подстроки (если перейти по ссылке, там они будут выделены синим).

Проблема заключается в том, что оно не делит на 2 группы так, как было задумано. Например, в строке `https://vk.com/public1234567` первая группа пустая, а вторая -- `public1234567`. Нужно сделать так, чтобы `id|public|club` был в первой группе, а все, что после - во второй. В примере первая группа должна быть `public`, вторая - `1234567`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У Вас в выражении вторая группа начинается с буквы. `1234567` с буквы не начинается, так что не может соответствовать второй группе.

Comment: Согласен. Придется как то по другому решать эту проблему :(

Comment: если поддерживаются условные подмаски, то ими пробуйте `(club|public|id)?(?(1)|[a-z])\w+$`. В джаваскрипт вроде нету, поэтому на сайте проверить не получается. Символьный класс это один символ, поэтому необязательно ему квантификатор {1} совать.

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас всегда 2 группа только цифры попробуйте так

```
(club|public|id)([0-9]{1}\w+)$
```

UPD

Если нужно что бы были 2 группы и если первая группа нету и все остальное должно быть в 2й группе тогда попробуйте

```
(club|public|id)?([a-z0-9]{1}\w+)$
```

и Почему не работает

> первая группа должна быть public, вторая - 1234567.

потому что 2я группа у Вас начинается с цифры. А вы указали что должно быть буква.

**Вы определите тогда ситуацию. Как должна начинаться 2я группа?**

Comment: Оно "не ловит" подстроки, начинающиеся на буквы. Например, `vk.com/pagename` или просто `pagename`. В моем изначальном выражении `[a-z]{1}\w` означает, что должно начинаться как минимум с 1 буквы, а дальше любые символы из `\w`. На скриншоте показано, что должно быть найдено.

Comment: UPD: `Вы определите тогда ситуацию. Как должна начинаться 2я группа?` - Вторая группа должна начинаться с буквы только тогда, когда первой - нет. В других случаях с цифры. Я так понимаю регулярными выражениями это за один "match" не сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?:^|\/)(?!\/)(club|public|id)?(\w+)$/
```

Проверка:

```
"http://vk.com/page_name\n\
vk.com/pagename\n\
pagename\n\
http://vk.com/club1234567\n\
vk.com/club1234567\n\
club1234567\n\
https://vk.com/public1234567\n\
vk.com/public1234567\n\
public1234567\n\
testgroup\n\
http://vk.com/id1234567\n\
vk.com/id1234567\n\
id1234567\n\
______________\n\
f123_____213\n\
324234234234\n\
id92343243242342".split("\n").map(function(s) {
  return s.match(/(?:^|\/)(?!\/)(club|public|id)?(\w+)$/);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Изначально проблема начинается с того, что после первой группы в образце текста идет цифра, а регулярное выражение подразумевает собой латинскую букву.
Самый простой способ решить эту проблему - добавить условие в регулярное выражение, что если первая группа встретилась, то за ней нет обязательной латинской буквы.
Выглядит такое выражение так:

```
(club|public|id)?((?(1)|[a-z])\w+)$
```

Живой пример: https://regex101.com/r/xK2gT3/2

Сравнение результатов работы моего (слева) и авторского (справа) выражения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зеленый текст - это успешно совпавшая первая группа, а розовая - вторая.

Comment: @Deadooshka теперь зачет ?